# What OS settings or Xcode settings could potentially lead to slow compile times?

Tags: xcode, macos

Me and my colleague are using the exact version of El Captian, Xcode8, MacbookPro(latest), Project (using git). We had the same issue with Xcode7...

Yet when he runs the project he gets it to run in 10 seconds for me it takes 40 seconds or more. This happens almost every day for every build.

In general are there any settings on the OS or Xcode that could make build times be so different? Is there way that I can analyze the Xcode performances?

Comment: Anti-virus software?

Comment: Settings in your scheme?

Comment: @gnasher729 Our macs are owned by company and they run scheduled anti-virus tests. Though we could have had different setups... I'll give that another look. If you we are using SVC wouldn't our schemes be all the same?

Comment: Shared schemes are the same, but often they are not the same.

Comment: @gnasher729 so what scheme settings would increase the compile time?